# Getting memory Address like values of my array when printing (C programming)

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create 8x8 array, but when I am printing that array, after [7][7] Element I am not getting the exact values that I assigned while creating the array.
My array is a follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int puzzle[8][8] = {
    //   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
        {0,0,2,0,4,0,5,9,3},//0
        {7,0,0,3,1,0,4,0,8},//1
        {4,0,0,8,0,5,1,0,2},//2
        {8,3,0,2,0,0,0,0,0},//3
        {0,9,6,0,0,0,3,5,0},//4
        {0,0,0,0,0,4,0,8,6},//5
        {3,0,1,5,0,9,0,0,7},//6
        {6,0,5,0,2,8,0,0,1},//7
        {0,4,0,0,7,0,6,0,0} //8
    }; 
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
    {
      printf("\n puzzle[%d][%d] = %d",i,j,puzzle[i][j]);
    }
  }


    return 0;
}
```

and I am getting output as

```
 puzzle[0][0] = 0
     puzzle[0][1] = 0
     puzzle[0][2] = 2
     puzzle[0][3] = 0
     puzzle[0][4] = 4
     puzzle[0][5] = 0
     puzzle[0][6] = 5
     puzzle[0][7] = 9
     puzzle[0][8] = 7
     puzzle[1][0] = 7
     puzzle[1][1] = 0
     puzzle[1][2] = 0
     puzzle[1][3] = 3
     puzzle[1][4] = 1
     puzzle[1][5] = 0
     puzzle[1][6] = 4
     puzzle[1][7] = 0
     puzzle[1][8] = 4
     puzzle[2][0] = 4
    puzzle[2][1] = 0
     puzzle[2][2] = 0
     puzzle[2][3] = 8
     puzzle[2][4] = 0
     puzzle[2][5] = 5
     puzzle[2][6] = 1
     puzzle[2][7] = 0
     puzzle[2][8] = 8
     puzzle[3][0] = 8
     puzzle[3][1] = 3
     puzzle[3][2] = 0
     puzzle[3][3] = 2
     puzzle[3][4] = 0
     puzzle[3][5] = 0
     puzzle[3][6] = 0
     puzzle[3][7] = 0
     puzzle[3][8] = 0
     puzzle[4][0] = 0
     puzzle[4][1] = 9
     puzzle[4][2] = 6
     puzzle[4][3] = 0
     puzzle[4][4] = 0
     puzzle[4][5] = 0
     puzzle[4][6] = 3
     puzzle[4][7] = 5
     puzzle[4][8] = 0
     puzzle[5][0] = 0
     puzzle[5][1] = 0
     puzzle[5][2] = 0
     puzzle[5][3] = 0
     puzzle[5][4] = 0
     puzzle[5][5] = 4
     puzzle[5][6] = 0
     puzzle[5][7] = 8
     puzzle[5][8] = 3
     puzzle[6][0] = 3
     puzzle[6][1] = 0
     puzzle[6][2] = 1
     puzzle[6][3] = 5
     puzzle[6][4] = 0
     puzzle[6][5] = 9
     puzzle[6][6] = 0
     puzzle[6][7] = 0
     puzzle[6][8] = 6
     puzzle[7][0] = 6
     puzzle[7][1] = 0
     puzzle[7][2] = 5
     puzzle[7][3] = 0
     puzzle[7][4] = 2
     puzzle[7][5] = 8
     puzzle[7][6] = 0
     puzzle[7][7] = 0
     puzzle[7][8] = -445142480
     puzzle[8][0] = -445142480
     puzzle[8][1] = 32765
     puzzle[8][2] = 480800256
     puzzle[8][3] = -129200335
     puzzle[8][4] = 0
     puzzle[8][5] = 0
     puzzle[8][6] = -2108403533
     puzzle[8][7] = 32522
     puzzle[8][8] = -2106304992
```

As you can see I am not getting exact values that I assigned to [7][8]th position.
The output I am getting looks like address or ids. I am not getting why it is happening, is it ide problem or is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: `< 9` should be `< 8`. Indexes go from 0 to 7.

Comment: Or rather, `int puzzle[8][8]` should be `int puzzle[9][9]`

Comment: You're declaring an 8x8 array, but filling it with 9x9 values.

Comment: Yeah understood  thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

As you already seem to understand, array elements are indexed beginning at position zero. So when you define an array of size n `arr[n]`, you can only hold `n` elements(0 to n - 1) in this array. Same applies for multi-dimensional arrays.

In your case you have only defined an array of size `8x8` which can hold only 64 elements. But you are trying to assign `9x9` 81 elements to your array. Thus, only indices `puzzle[0][0]` to `puzzle[7][7]` are accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler shall issue a message for this initialization

```
int puzzle[8][8] = {
//   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
    {0,0,2,0,4,0,5,9,3},//0
    {7,0,0,3,1,0,4,0,8},//1
    {4,0,0,8,0,5,1,0,2},//2
    {8,3,0,2,0,0,0,0,0},//3
    {0,9,6,0,0,0,3,5,0},//4
    {0,0,0,0,0,4,0,8,6},//5
    {3,0,1,5,0,9,0,0,7},//6
    {6,0,5,0,2,8,0,0,1},//7
    {0,4,0,0,7,0,6,0,0} //8
};
```

because elements of the array are arrays with `8` elements bur you are supplying `9` initializers for each element.

And if an array has `N` elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, N)`.